# Perform task on app upgrade

Tags: android

I'm writing a new version of my Android app and upon upgrade I need to perform a certain task.  Is there anything similar to onUpgrade that is used for Sqlite but instead for the entire application?

If there is nothing similar, I assume I could store a flag in shared prefs saying the application has been upgraded but I would rather not have to run a check every time someone opens the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The easiest way is to keep that flag in persistent memory, which can be checked during instantiation of the application object. If you're interested in keeping upstart time as short as possible (who isn't?), you can store the version in an ordinary file as an integer using DataOutputStream and DataInputStream. That way you'll stay away from the overhead of parsing a SharedPrefs file.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clearification, this IS indeed possible.

**1)** Create *BroadcastReceiver*

**2)** Let Receiver *listen on the following intent*(min sdk 12)

```
<receiver android:name="MyUpgradeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**3)** In the onReceive method of the receiver you can *get the new version* info with
   PackageInfo pInfo =

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
int versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

**4)** *Compare it* with the old one - e.g. we save the version always in the shared preferences, so that we can compare it with the new version. On every call of the receiver the version info in the preferences is updated